# Excel Preview On Html

Tags: html, excel, iframe

I Wanted to Excel sheet embedded in Html. I tried On IFrame, but it downloads the file. In other case Pdf, Image on Iframe is working good. But Excel, Word is not working. Please suggest another possible way to preview the excel sheet on HTML.
Here My Code Is:

```html
<iframe src="img/sample.xlsx" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way you can embed the workbook into your web page, but you have to host it on OneDrive and then get an embed link from there:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081

Here is an example:

https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/how-to-capitalize-names-in-excel/

Comment: Thanks, But without hosting OneDrive is there any possible to preview the excel.

Comment: @Jayaswaminathan not without coding it all yourself, unfortunately. What's wrong with the OneDrive solution? It's super simple.

Comment: yes, It's simple. But in my scenario not single file to display. we can dynamically upload multiple files and uploaded files shows on preview one by one.

Comment: Your browser can't normally display xslx files, right? So that's why it can't display it in an iframe. Any solution is going to involve parsing the content and outputting it into a format the browser can display.

Comment: @Jayaswaminathan you can upload all of the workbooks you need to OneDrive, get all of the embed URLs, then dynamically update your links as you need. The only painful part is uploading the docs. If you need an automated way to do that to OneDrive, I'm sure it's easy since you can have OneDrive on your machine, move the files to there, and let OneDrive sync the files up. OneDrive also has a set of APIs that you can use to your advantage as well.

Comment: @Jayaswaminathan one other idea is to take the workbook and save the first sheet as an image on your server, then show that `preview`, but this is not the same as embedding an Excel workbook on a website.

Comment: Thanks @JosephSerido Its Cool.My Excel sheet contains formula's and calculation.we can display the formula's and calculation.

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically upload files use https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

demo https://oss.sheetjs.com/

site https://sheetjs.com/

```
function handleFile(e) {


var files = e.target.files, f = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});

    /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
input_dom_element.addEventListener('change', handleFile, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that looking for answer and ends up here, you can try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=your_excel_file_url" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="0">
    </body>
</html>
```